# What is the computer "doing" when it is running slow and task manager is not showing any CPU activity?

Tags: windows, performance

Typical example is when shutting down a memoryintensive application. It can take quite a while before the computer gets back up to speed. Is there some inherent cost in releasing memory? Or is it throttled by some kind of harddrive activity, and if so is there any good way to track that?

I usually bring up task manager when a computer is running slow, and usually sorting by cpu activity can show what process is causing the problem, but sometimes there is no activity showing. And yes I "show processes from all users", I have been wondering this since the days win2k :)

Comment: Hardware issue is a possibility. HDD issue is likely. Memory issue is also likely but more often causing a BSOD rather than just a froze, and keep going.

Comment: It's probably all the memory book-keeping. Pages have to be deallocated from both the page table and page file, on top of any files that have to be saved to disk. What does disk activity look like while the application is closing? Does the HDD hit 100% utilization?

Comment: The point of the question was to be rather broad, and it was excellently answered below, so I would not call it too broad!

Comment: @DarthAndroid I'm not that familiar with the page terms but I guess thats basically the same advice as in the answer below? I'll learn to look for HDD activity to read my system better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about having enough RAM and the speed of your RAM and HDD.

Consider these specs since you did not provide any:

```
OS:          Windows 7 64-bit
CPU:         Core 2 duo 2GHz
RAM:         4GB PC2 5300
HDD:         500GB 5400 RPM
VRAM on HDD: 8GB (virtual RAM or Page File - default size is RAM x2)
```

Here is a break down of what happens:

- OS takes 2GB baseline to just run OS
- Open up large app like photoshop
- Photoshop needs 1GB which is fine and dandy
- Start working on a hi-res image and now you are at 300 layers
- Photoshop has been increasing it's RAM consumption to a specified limit set in your preferences (say 3GB)
- Windows is like "oh crap, let me offload some non-essential processes to VRAM"
- Windows now has 1GB in RAM and 1GB in VRAM
- At this point if you open a web browser then it will be quite slow to open it
- This is because items in VRAM are frequently accessed by the OS so your HDD is choking on regular Windows processes
- Save work and close photoshop
- RAM is FREE!!!
- Windows has to move it's processes from VRAM back to regular RAM which is the slowdown that you describe
- 5400RPM HDD is dirt slow compared to RAM so the HDD is the bottleneck until it is no longer being used for VRAM

You can track your HDD activity by using Windows Performance Monitor:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor-disk-counters-explained.aspx

Comment: Very clear answer, thanks. I will learn to read the HDD activity and relate that to ram/vram transfer as well.

Comment: I'm glad my post was helpful to you! After reading the comments above I realize I may have used the wrong term (interchangeably). The VRAM I was referring to is also known as the Page File which is a section of your HDD reserved for memory offload. It's default size if double your real RAM. I will update the post for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I can give is use Process Explorer to look more deeply into what is running.  It's far more in-depth than the usual Task Manager etc:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx